# What are special files like CHANGELOG/LICENSE/VERSION/CONTRIBUTING/new_issue called?

Tags: git, github, repository, gitlab, naming

Popular repository-hosting platforms like GitHub.com and GitLab enable the use of special files (readme-files) like `README`/`CHANGELOG`/`LICENSE`/`VERSION`/`CONTRIBUTING` (or similar eg ending in `.md`) and offer direct links to them or include them in the project website according to their meaning.

If I want to search for available files in general (not one project/repo) what should i search for? **What are these files called?**

At least [Changelog counts as Readme according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=README&oldid=709959347). So one could call them *Readme-files*. 
But there are additional files like issue/pull request templates (eg `ISSUE_TEMPLATE` for GitHub) or similar (depending on the platform).

If there is no prevalent convention we can start a discussion (https://github.com/kmindi/special-files-in-repository-root/issues/1)

This question is not for listing available special files or their respective file naming convention. For naming conventions of Changelog see for example [keepachangelog.com](http://keepachangelog.com/).
Its also not restricted to git repositories, but highly related because thats where I expect the popular uses.

Comment: Whether a file in a repository has a particular status is probably dependent on the repository and not Git.  Using your example, one option would be to clone the repo locally and then search for files containing all caps.

Answer (score 1):

> What are special files like CHANGELOG/LICENSE/VERSION/CONTRIBUTING/new_issue called?

They are not called anything special (there are "metadata" of sorts for your project).
They are *interpreted* by the repository *hosting* server (like GitHub or GitLab) a certain way, but that is entirely up to that hosting server to highlight certain files.
But from the point of view of the repository managed by those services, they are just files.

Even their naming convention isn't completely fixed. See for instance [issue 14611](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14611)

> > When I click add contribution guide I get a page to create a file named `CONTRIBUTING.md` however when I go to add a license or changelog I get files without the `.md` extension.
> >     I think this is a bug, as all of them should have consistent behavior and have the `.md` extension.
>
> The filenames were based on observed use in open source repositories, where `LICENSE` and `CHANGELOG` are relatively simple files, and `CONTRIBUTING.md` is a more complex document.